# Hero is fired by his company and his wife leaves him too

Tags: identify-this-movie

The movie starts with the hero being fired because he saved the company in a law suit and now can never do anything like that again. When he gets home to be consoled by his wife he finds a note that she has left him. Every time he tries to talk to someone about his misfortune a new disaster happens. In the end he meets with his sister (?) who is dying of cancer. She tells him not to be so obsessed with himself and get over it, or something like that.

I can't remember any actors or the director. What is the name of this French movie?

I saw it between 89 and 94. I think it was from the same year.

Comment: WHen did you watch it? What time was it likely from?

Comment: @Christian Answered in the text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly *La crise* from 1992? The [plot summary](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0104025/) on IMDB indicates that this is a film about a lawyer who becomes unemployed and single on the same day. There are a couple other similarities with what you've mentioned above as well.

Comment: The first user review makes it clear that this is the movie I am looking for. Now the where to get this as dvd with English or German syncro or subtitles ?